# Polymer-Dart iron-list not binding to selected-item

Tags: polymer, dart

This is a subset of the code, using `<iron-list>` with:

HTML

```
<iron-list selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" selection-enabled>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{inputs}}">
    [[item.name]]
  </template>
</iron-list>
{{selectedItem}}
```

Dart

```
class className extends PolymerElement {
  @property var selectedItems;
  @property List inputs = new List.from([{"name": "fred"}]);
}
```

Upon selection, `selectedItem` is supposed to have the value of the selected item, but it is still `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The light DOM of `<iron-list>` should not be a list of items, but rather a single base `<template>` (not `dom-repeat`, `dom-if`, etc.), which specifies the desired DOM for *each* item:

```
<iron-list ...>
  <template>
    ...
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

That light DOM cannot be a text node:

```
<iron-list ...>
  <template>
    <!-- Cannot be a text node like this -->
    <!-- [[item.name]] -->

    <div>[[item.name]]</div>
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

The item array data should be bound to `<iron-list>.items`:

```
<iron-list items="[[items]]" ...>
```

Altogether, it should look similar to this:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => [{name: 'Fred'}, {name: 'John'}]
      }
    },
    _computeClass: function(isSelected) {
      return isSelected ? 'selected' : '';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-list/iron-list.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        iron-list {
          height: 50px;
        }
        .item.selected {
          background: lightblue;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
      </style>

      <iron-list items="[[items]]" selection-enabled selected-item="{{selectedItem}}">
        <template>
          <div class$="item [[_computeClass(selected)]]">[[item.name]]</div>
        </template>
      </iron-list>

      <h1>selected name: [[selectedItem.name]]</h1>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oBQZNr?editors=1010)